# Caret package installation in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I am facing problem in installing caret in R. I have tried changing the repo and also installing individual packages minqa,lme4 etc. But nothing works.
Error that I am getting

```
   eg++: error: [1]: No such file or directory
g++: error: TRUE: No such file or directory
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'minqa.so' failed
make: *** [minqa.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/home/himaanshu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/minqa’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpjR5OCn/downloaded_packages’`



    R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.0                         
year           2015                        
month          04                          
day            16                          
svn rev        68180                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
nickname       Full of Ingredients
```

Comment: Do you have the system package `make` installed? If not, try `sudo apt-get install make` and then try again.

Comment: Same error I am getting again

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear: package minqa fails to install.

Deal with that first.  And show us error for minqa itself.

Once you have it installed, install caret.

PS For what it is worth, all of those install fine on my Ubuntu systems...

Comment: This is a fairly common issue; that package is a pita to install. Incidentally, you may not need it if you don't use adaptive resampling. The dependency is there since `caret` suggests `BradleyTerry2` which depends on `lme4` which imports `minqa`